# Scheduling a timertask

Tags: java, timer, timertask

So, I'm trying to make a java program which will execute a task every 10 seconds starting from 9 am. Here's the code that I am facing problem with.

```
public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        new Main();
    }

    public Main(){
        Timer timer=new Timer();
        TimerTask task=new TimerTask(){
            
           public void run(){
               System.out.println("Its 9 am!");
           }

        };

        Calendar calendar=Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,9);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);

        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task,calendar.getTime(),10000);

    }
}
```

**but when I run the java code even if it is not 9 am it starts to execute the task.**

Comment: What do you mean with _before 9 am it immediately starts to execute the task._?

Comment: I just gave it a try with different starting times - works as expected!

Comment: @dan1st I meant that even if it is not 9 am on my clock still it executes the task

Comment: Where is your code to wait around until 9:00 AM comes around?

Comment: @MarkStewart as I have added calendar.getTime() arguement in the scheduleAtFixedRate method, it shuld wait till 9 am right? If I am getting this wrong please direct me to the right way.

Comment: I've never played with the Timer nor TimerTask class, so just guessing.  I added more debug statements in your code and looks like it was running the `run()` command instantly, over and over, without waiting. Add `System.out.println("Got to here 2.2 at " + new java.util.Date() + " and cal is " + calendar);` to your code after setting the `calendar` values... and see if it is what you expected...

Comment: So, I've figured out the problem I was facing. Actually when it is past 9 am or the time specified it works fine, but if I run the code after the specific time it immediately starts executing the task, doesn't even wait for the period(10 seconds). So is there a way to handle this situation, where if I run the code after the time specified it will automatically schedule the task for the next day?

Comment: Maybe checking the `TimerTask. scheduledExecutionTime` results? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html#scheduledExecutionTime--  and note the "The return value is undefined if the task has yet to commence its first execution."